# Want to send webcam stream to wowza using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, wowza

I am new to both Wowza and to FFMPEG. I have been testing with ffmpeg and I am able to create local files with video and audio. For example:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" myvideo.mpeg

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -pix_fmt yuv420p myvideoandaudio.mp4
```

What I want to do is send the stream of my webcam to the Wowza server I have installed locally. I have searched several forums, including this one, and have tried multiple commands but still no luck. I would like to have someone point me in the right direction. Following Wowza's instructions, I created a Stream File called mystream, which has a stream UI of udp://0.0.0.0:10100. Also, the application connection settings say that the server's IP is 10.160.XX.XXX and port 1935. I am using Windows, and the "Shared" version of the FFMPEG downloads. I even changed the XML file following the instructions here, trying to send user credentials (during installation, Wowza asked to create credentials if I was going to use streaming):

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?233-How-to-secure-publishing-from-an-RTMP-encoder-that-does-not-support-authentication-(ModuleSecureURLParams)

I have tried all the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/mystream
-- failed to connect socket

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/mystream
-- failed to read RTMP packet header

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://10.160.XX.XXX:1935/live/mystream
-- failed to read RTMP packet header

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://10.160.XX.XXX/live/mystream
-- failed to read RTMP packet header

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream
-- failed to read RTMP packet header

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/mystream
-- writeN, rtmp send error 10053

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -f flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 rtmp://10.160.XX.XXX:1935/live/ivanstream
-- failed to read RTMP packet header

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b:v 900k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:10100
-- conversion failed

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -r 10 -async 1 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 24k -ar 22050 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:10100
-- conversion failed

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -s 512x288 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1024k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream
-- failed to read rtmp packet header

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://10.160.XX.XXX:1935/live?doPublish=12345/mystream
-- failed to read rtmp packet header

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -r 40 -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -r 40 -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://10.160.XX.XXX:1935/live/mystream
-- rtmp header error

ffmpeg -y -f dshow -s 640x480 -r:v 15 -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -c:v libx264 -b:v -pix_fmt yuv420p -vb 450 -an -map 0:0 -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:10000 -flags +global_header -c:a libvo_aacenc -vn -map 0:1 -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:10002 > 10000.sdp
--unable to find suitable output format yuv420p
```

References:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?25777-Live-Webcam-feed-to-WOWZA-Server-over-RTMP-with-H264-encoding

http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/23-other-software-technologies/258-preventing-real-time-buffer-error-causing-ffmpeg-to-drop-frames-in-screencast

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?233-How-to-secure-publishing-from-an-RTMP-encoder-that-does-not-support-authentication-(ModuleSecureURLParams)

Thank you.

Comment: You have to decide what method of ingestion you want to use. The stream file with udp:// is used for inputs such as MPEG-TS. If you want to use RTMP, [see this guide](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36). The reason for `conversion failed` may be that your `ffmpeg` was not compiled with `libx264` support. Without the full console output is hard to say.

Comment: I am still going through the guide. I did not compile ffmpeg, I just downloaded the Windows Shared version from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide may be helpful for you

Comment: I was able to generate the commands I was looking for:

    ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (Parallels Audio Con" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict -2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://sourceuser:sourceassword@10.0.XXX.XXX:1935/live/mywebcam
    
-- streams feed with both video and audio


    ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict -2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://sourceuser:sourcepassword@10.0.XXX.XXX:1935/live/sample
    
-- streams file with both video and audio